# Biblatex is zeroing Bob! Is Biblatex incompatible with titling, Memoir and more?

Tags: biblatex, memoir, incompatibility, xparse, titling

Consider the following Minimal Working Example (MWE):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,titling}
\NewDocumentCommand\makethis {  } {%
  {\LARGE\theauthor\bigskip\par}
}
\author{Bob}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\begin{document}
\makethis
\end{document}
```

I would expect this - naïvely, as it turns out - to typeset the single word `Bob` in `\LARGE` letters. In fact, it renders thus:

[image: zeroed Bob]

[Note that without `xparse`, I would be giving you an NMWE (Non-Working Minimal Example) rather than an MWE, since replacing `\NewDocumentCommand` with `\newcommand` yields a compilation error as opposed to zero success.]

Or consider this MWE using Memoir:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\author{Bob}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\begin{document}
\theauthor
\end{document}
```

Again, Bob is zeroed by Biblatex:

[image: zeroed Bob]

Removing the lines loading Biblatex resolves the issue, as does specifying `\author{Bob}` *after* loading Biblatex rather than *before*.

When Bob is defined *after* loading Biblatex, `\theauthor` resolves, as I'd expected, to `Bob`:

```
> \theauthor=macro:
->Bob.
l.100 \show\theauthor
```

When, however, Bob is defined *before* loading Biblatex, `\theauthor` resolves rather differently:

```
> \theauthor=macro:
->\@arabic \c@author .
l.100 \show\theauthor
```

Now I can easily protect Bob from being zeroed in other ways. Of greater concern is the fact that Biblatex appears to be competing with `titling`, Memoir and similar packages/classes for the use of `\theauthor` with, I assume, Biblatex using a counter named `author`, while its competitors define `\theauthor` to preserve the value passed to `\author`.

How should this incompatibility best be resolved? I'm guessing it has something to do with this code in `biblatex_.sty`:

```
\def\do#1{%
  \newcounter{#1}%
  \newcounter{saved#1}%
  \appto\abx@dobooleans{\do{more#1}}}

\abx@donames
\abx@dornames
\abx@dolists
```

which possibly ?? has something to do with defining booleans for conditional processing with things like `\ifauthor`. But, if so, this seems to rely rather dangerously on macro names which lack any sort of package prefix and are really quite likely to get inadvertently overwritten or to inadvertently overwrite other things.

Equally, Memoir and `titling` using `\theauthor`, `\thetitle` and `\thedate` has always struck me as unfortunate given the use of `\the...` for typesetting counters. But several classes and packages have used this convention for some time when it is desirable to preserve the values given to `\author`, `\title` and `\date` beyond the use of `\maketitle`.

A superficial `grep` of the first level of sub-directories in `tex/latex/` suggests that this issue may also affect several thesis classes, `uspatent`, `seminar`, `droit-fr`, `ltugboat`, `ametsoc` and `abntex2` etc.  However, since I'm not familiar with most of these, I cannot say immediately whether the issue is likely to produce any symptoms in their cases and have not pursued the investigation further.

Comment: I don't think that the `biblatex` behavoiur is new. I have already observed this for some time for other packages classes.

Comment: @Guido Then I've somehow inadvertently avoided it. That seemed unlikely, but I didn't want to rule it out - hence my uncertainty. What really concerns me here is that Biblatex presumably *needs* this counter for something, so what happens when it gets overwritten all the time?

Comment: For what I can see, the problem was there at least since August last year.  For me the problem was a compilation error (the command \c@author) already defined (it is used by the class I was using) and I did not see any visible effects (at the end I undefined it and load biblatex after).  I agree with your concerns. For what I can see the counter is used in `\abx@donames`

Comment: @Guido Thanks. I had just reached that conclusion myself. `biblatex_legacy.sty` uses `\c@author` explicitly, but I think it is implicit with Biber, as you say. And I've deleted my obviously mistaken guess about the newness of the behaviour - I've clearly just coincidentally escaped for some reason before this. I think both packages are to blame, but Biblatex's seems odd given its general liking of prefixes.

Comment: @Guido Was the class Memoir by any chance? Or another class based on Memoir? You made me realise the problem must be more general. I recall now that Memoir and `titling` share this code. A bunch of other classes etc. use `\theauthor` if grepping them is anything to go by!

Comment: It is a class for IOS Press proceedings/books (`IOS-Book-Article.cls`), and it is use as a counter.

Comment: @Guido Ah, right. There are some similar cases in TeX Live. Memoir uses it like `titling` and some other cases are like that. Others use it as a counter. *Some* of these probably prohibit Biblatex anyway. But that's certainly not going to be true of Memoir and probably the thesis classes I found. Thanks for the info.

Comment: It might be worth opening an issue on  the GitHub biblatex repository

Comment: @Guido Yes, if people think it is a bug, that's appropriate. But I'm not sure whether the author will see it that way.

Comment: An issue is not necessarily a bug :-)  Given, the number of other packages, classes that might be affected, it is an issue the biblatex developers can consider. For what I can see it is just used internally, and it is not part of the external interface. Thus an internal modification is unlikely to affect biblatex styles.

Comment: This is very unfortunate, while most uses of `\c@author` and friends are internal, there are some calls to `\value{author}` etc. in the `.def` files and I assume custom styles also use this. So it isn't a matter of simply renaming the name counter to something that avoids clashes. I assume it is quite safe to override `biblatex`'s name counters in the preamble as they are only used in `biblatex`'s macros, where they are re-filled with the correct values before use.

Comment: A quick search on the latex directory of TeXlive indicates that `\value{author}` is used only 6 times and in 5 files (biblatex-fiwi, and biblatex-publist). It is a change less invasive than the recent change of the part name format.

Comment: @Guido There are some more `\value{editor}` and `\value{translator}`s out there (`biblatex-chicago`, `biblatex-historian`, `biblatex-dw`, `biblatex-jura`, `biblatex-musos`, `biblatex-trad`, `historische-zeitschrift`)

Comment: Imho the problem is more in the use of `\theauthor` by the classes/packages. Everyone should know that latex automatically creates a `\the<counter>` with every \newcounter{counter}.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes. As I say, I think this is unfortunate for precisely this reason. Still, several classes and packages in widespread use now rely on this. There is also the issue of other classes/packages which use an identically named counter. Biblatex isn't more to blame than the other packages/classes. Probably all you can say is that at least some of them used `\theauthor` first ;). I think this is a bug. But *whose* bug is another matter.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer In a way that would mean that one should never start a command with `the`: so I can't define a `theorem` environment, because someone might need an `orem` counter. `;-)` `biblatex` is probably a bit greedy here using a very generic name (`author`) for something that is essentially a lower level thing (though I have to admit that `\value{author}` and friends appear on style level).

Comment: @moewe: I tried to image what would happen if \theorem were banned ;-). biblatex should naturally if possible try to use internal or local names and counters. It could e.g. save an existing definition of \theauthor and restore it and use its own (if actually needed) only inside the bibliography/cites.  But the \theauthor from the class isn't right either ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer After the global definition of the counters all later assignments seem to be so local that `\theauthor` isn't altered any more `\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\author{Bob}
\begin{document}
\theauthor
\cite{sigfridsson,aksin}
\printbibliography
\theauthor
\end{document}` seems absolutely fine. And you are absolutely right that `\theauthor` is a bit of an unfortunate name (though I can understand why it was chosen).

Comment: @moewe: Imho it is a good idea to set \author and \title late (actually after \begin{document} to allow for babel shortcuts) anyway.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, but it is handy not to have to set in in the document at all ;). I agree that the use of `\theauthor` by Memoir, `ltugboat`, `titling`, Biblatex etc. is unfortunate. *Something* is not bound to end up broken somewhere. Hence, really, the question: how can the problems best be addressed given where things are now and not where they might have been? ;)

Comment: @moewe If Biblatex could save and restore `\theauthor` or whatever, maybe that would be the best general solution?

Comment: The problem was "caused" in biblatex by a generalisation of the datamodel code for names where we need to automatically generate counters for anything that's a name in the datamodel. `author` is of course one of these. It is tricky because these counters are used all over the place and in custom styles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I put in a save/restore for all such "bare" counters derived from the datamodel. This doesn't seem to impact anything as far as I can tell - all test docs generate identical output. The problem was larger than `\theauthor` as the default datamodel also generates `\thetitle` etc. DEV version 3.4 has this fix.